# Laravel Eloquent like relationship with whereHas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to search inside a relationship and my query is

```
            $records = Store::orderBy($columnName,$columnSortOrder)
               ->where('store_id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
                ->whereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                     $query->where('name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
                })                 
               ->select('*')
               ->skip($start)
               ->take($rowperpage)
               ->get();
```

and returns a query

```
    SELECT * FROM `store` WHERE `store_id` LIKE '%San%' AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `customers` 
WHERE `store`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` AND `name` LIKE '%San%') ORDER BY 
`inv_id` ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

What I want is or with relation

```
SELECT * FROM `store` WHERE `store_id` LIKE '%San%' OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `customers` 
WHERE `store`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` AND `name` LIKE '%San%') ORDER BY 
`inv_id` ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: I think you just have to change whereHas() to orWhere()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `whereHas` use `orWhereHas`

```
$records = Store::orderBy($columnName,$columnSortOrder)
           ->where('store_id', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('customer', function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                 $query->where('name', 'like', '%' .$searchValue . '%');
            })                 
           ->select('*')
           ->skip($start)
           ->take($rowperpage)
           ->get();
```